# getting the text from dialog box to the main activity

Tags: android

Hi I am using a options menu ,I just want to display a dialog box with two edittexts and ok and cancel buttons. when i pressed ok i want to send the data entered in textfield to main activity. can any one please help me how can i do that.

Answer (score 5):

You can EditText in your dialog.. like this, (For one editText i m writing it)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"     android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
   android:orientation="vertical">     
 <EditText         android:id="@+id/myEditText"       
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"      
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Then inflate the View from within your Dialog and get the content of the EditText.

```
  private Dialog myTextDialog() {    
     final View layout = View.inflate(this, R.layout.myDialog, null);   
       final EditText savedText = ((EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.myEditText));    

      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);   
      builder.setIcon(0); 

      builder.setPositiveButton("Save", new Dialog.OnClickListener() {     
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {  
              String myString = savedText.getText().toString().trim();   
          }   
      });   
  builder.setView(layout);  
   return builder.create(); 
 }
```

myString will hold the content of your EditText

Answer (score 1):

If you're starting the dialog from the main activity, all you need to do is initialize a variable in your activity class and set it's value in dialog box, nothing special. Hope this helps.